# Loop by column from a table

Tags: loop, table-field, table

How can I loop from col2 to col4 ? Or loop by column heading handle?
Remplace {{ row.***col2*** }}

```
<ul class="features small-font-size">
  {% for row in block.tableHandle %}

      <li data-feature="{{ row.description }}">{{ row.col2 }}</li>

  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're after?

```
{% for row in block.tableHandle %}

    {% for columnHandle, columnValue in row %}
        {# If not col1 #}
        {% if loop.index != 1 %}
            <p>Do whatever you want with: {{ columnValue }}</p>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I'm following the question, but if you just want to output every `col2` and `col4` row value, it'd be as simple as:

```
<ul>
    {% for row in block.tableHandle %}
        <li data-feature="{{ row.description }}">{{ row.col2 }} - {{ row.col4 }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

There isn't a native way to loop directly by a column's handle.

Comment: I want to loop by column. Output all rows in column col2, all rows for col3 and all rows in col4 but in a loop. I don't want to repeat the codes 3 times.